# Yup validator allow multiple types like string and number

Tags: javascript, yup

I have a API and using yup to validate the request parameters.

I have the case that some legacy versions of our app are sending a value as string.
We would like to change it to number and the validator should accept both types string "or" number.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by chaining [mixed()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#mixed) to your validation schema. It allows you to accept multiple types or specify only a few types. I like the idea of using a test to verify based on each type you want to accept. Something like what is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60656255/yup-validation-can-the-same-field-accept-different-types).

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
  myvalue: yup.lazy((value) =>
    typeof value === 'object'
      ? yup.object().required('Required field').typeError('Required field') // typeError is necessary here, otherwise we get a bad-looking yup error
      : yup.string().required('Required field')
  ),
```

source: [github](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/549#issuecomment-855698808)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const schema = yup.object({
  mixedField: yup.mixed().test(
  'is-string-or-number',
  'The field must be either a string or a number',
  value => typeof value === 'string' || typeof value === 'number'
  )
});
```